# C++ Pointer loses value in inheritance after function call.

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I have an assignment that involves AVL trees and rank trees.
In this specific assignment we need to implement a Rank AVL tree, which keeps in nodes another information. 
I have this problem:
I made an AVL tree and for the Rank tree I chose to use inheritance. 
In the "Insert" function of the Rank tree I call another function called: "setAllHeights" which receives a node as an argument. 
However, when I see the values in the debugger of the argument, I see that the function receives NULL pointer. 
I don't understand why because before I entered "setAllHeights" function, I checked the value of the argument and it most definitely was not NULL. 
What could be the problem, and why is it happening?

I will very much appreciate your help.

The code of the function Insert:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
bool RAVL<T, Compare>::insert(const T& data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new (nothrow) RNode<T, Compare>(data, NULL);
        if (!root)
            throw AllocationError();
        size++;
        return true;
    }
    Compare cmp;
    RNode<T, Compare> *v;
    if (find(data, &v))
        return false;
    if (cmp(v->data, data)) {
        v->right = new (nothrow) RNode<T, Compare>(data, v);
        if (!v->right)
            throw AllocationError();
    } else {
        v->left = new (nothrow) RNode<T, Compare>(data, v);
        if (!v->left)
            throw AllocationError();
    }
    Node<T,Compare> * n=v;
    AVL<T,Compare>::setAllHeights(n);
    rebalance(v);
    size++;
    return true;
}
```

The code of the setAllHeights function:

```
template<class T, class Compare>
void AVL<T, Compare>::setAllHeights(Node<T, Compare> *n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    setHeight(n);
    setAllHeights(n->parent);
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: This is exactly what I did.. I saw in the debugger that the function receives NULL pointer.. I just don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: Are you doing a debug build?   You can see strange things like that sometimes in optimized builds.

Comment: @kidneyThief And what about providing a [MCVE] here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you aren't initializing v, and thus when you assign it to n, that isn't being initialized either. You would need to call v = new RNode(...) , or whatever your logic is.

Comment: I am initializing v by the function "find". It finds me the node I need to insert after. The function works. I just want to know why the function receives NULL pointer when it's not actually NULL in the debugger.

Comment: @kidneyThief **[MCVE]** in your question!!!!

Comment: I will try. Thanks.